# Spring security + mvc special characters encoding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding

I have one project with Spring security implemented, the project works smooth, the views looks OK, no problem with encoding except for logging messages and e-mail messages.

***E-mail:***

On my auth controller I have one method to send e-mails to reset passwords, I generate the url on the controller

```
final String url = contextPath + "/user/resetPassword?id=" + user.getId();
```

If I use a template, something like this:

```
        title = "Restablecer contraseña";
        body = String.format("%s:\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Click on this link and you can reset your password:\n" +
                        "%s\n" +
                user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName(),
                url);

        String encodingOptions = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        msg.setHeader("Content-Type", encodingOptions);
        msg.addRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(user.getEmail()));
        msg.addFrom(new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress(env.getProperty("support.email"))});

        msg.setSubject(title, "UTF-8");
        msg.setText(body, "UTF-8");
```

The url generated is:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/resetPassword?id=3D6
```

But the correct url is:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/resetPassword?id=6
```

***LOGGER:***

Something similar happen over the logger.

```
LOGGER.info("Restablecer contraseña");
```

Over the console the message is:

```
Restablecer su contraseÃ±a
```

This situation about logger is very very strange, works fine for moments, works wrong for moments.

Any ideas?

***My config:***

**IntelliJ 14**

**Apache 8.0.15**

web.xml with org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>org.admin.spring</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <!-- This filter has to come before other filters. -->
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>localizationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>localizationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <name>AUTHSESSION</name>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

On the apache server.xml configuration I have been change the 2 connectors with URIEncoding="UTF-8"

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

WebMvcConfigurerAdapter Class:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    return messageSource;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the console is quite common... the console or application you're using to see the logs doesn't support UTF-8 (I would bet you're running your app on windows).

The issue with the email looks strange, as `3D` is the octal representation of the `=` symbol.

#### edit

Nothing comes to my mind of what could be wrong in the email you generate other than the actual code that generates the email (as I don't think that your email provider or email client will change the url). When you configure JavaMail set the property [`mail.debug` to `true`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) to get more information about what your app is sending to the email server. I'm quite sure you'll find that you're sending the strange characters

Also, try debugging the your code line by line (going inside each method) from the moment you generate the url string until the moment JavaMail sends the email to pinpoint the exact location where those characters are added.

Comment: Ok, good about the console (yes, at the moment I use win). About the url, is very strange, if I send only the URL to the body works ok, but if I use the string.Format "templating" nop. Any idea?

Comment: do you have any idea about the problem over the url?? maybe something between windows and apache?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why you get the characters `3D` in the url. You'll probably need to debug the code to ensure that there's nothing wrong when you generate the url and that text is added to the email.